# Selecting distinct column values in SQLAlchemy/Elixir

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, python-elixir

In a little script I'm writing using SQLAlchemy and Elixir, I need to get all the distinct values for a particular column. In ordinary SQL it'd be a simple matter of

```
SELECT DISTINCT `column` FROM `table`;
```

and I know I could just run that query "manually," but I'd rather stick to the SQLAlchemy declarative syntax (and/or Elixir) if I can. I'm sure it must be possible, I've even seen allusions to this sort of thing in the SQLAlchemy documentation, but I've been hunting through that documentation for hours (as well as that of Elixir) and I just can't seem to actually figure out how it would be done. So what am I missing?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

You can query column properties of mapped classes and the Query class has a generative `distinct()` method:

```
for value in Session.query(Table.column).distinct():
     pass
```

Comment: hm, well I could have sworn I tried that and it gave me an error... but apparently not. It works, thanks!

Comment: Trying that, I get a 'Query' object is not callable error... :\ Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: kchau: could it be tht you are trying to call the query_property descriptor on a class instead of the query method on Session? So SomeClass.query(...) instead of Session.query(...)?

Comment: Ants: I have a scoped_session like: `my_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=my_engine, autoflush=True, autocommit=True))`, and then I'm trying to call: `my_session.query(SysSegCode.sysCode).distinct()` to get the list of unique values...

Comment: Never mind, issue resolved. Was doing a combination of things wrong... was trying to instantiate an instance of an Entity and then calling a property on that entity.

Comment: If you are using a table construct instead of the declarative mapping here, you can do the same thing with:  `Session.query(Table.columns.my_column).distinct()...`

Answer (score 11):

For this class:

```
class Assurance(db.Model):
    name = Column(String)
```

you can do this:

```
assurances = []
for assurance in Assurance.query.distinct(Assurance.name):
    assurances.append(assurance.name)
```

and you will have the list of distinct values

Comment: This will only work as intended in Postgresql, which has the DISTINCT ON extension. The accepted answer is far more portable and avoids selecting the extra columns.

Answer (score 9):

I wanted to count the distinct values, and using `.distinct()` and `.count()` would count first, resulting in a single value, then do the distinct. I had to do the following

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
Session.query(func.count(func.distinct(Table.column))
```

Answer (score 5):

For class,

```
class User(Base):
    name = Column(Text)
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Method 1: Using load_only

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import load_only
records= (db_session.query(User).options(load_only(name)).distinct().all())
values = [record[0] if len(record) == 1 else record for record in records]  # list of distinct values
```

Method2: without any imports

```
records = db_session.query(User.name).distinct().all()
l_values = [record.__dict__[l_columns[0]] for record in records]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for user in session.query(users_table).distinct():
    print user.posting_id
```

Answer (score 3):

SQL Alchemy version 2 encourages the use of the `select()` function. You can use an SQL Alchemy `table` to build a select statement that extracts unique values:

```
select(distinct(table.c.column_name))
```

SQL Alchemy [2.0 migration ORM usage](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/migration_20.html#migration-orm-usage):

> "The biggest visible change in SQLAlchemy 2.0 is the use of Session.execute() in conjunction with select() to run ORM queries, instead of using Session.query()."

Reproducible example using pandas to collect the unique values.

### Define and insert the iris dataset

Define an ORM structure for the iris dataset, then use pandas to insert the
data into an SQLite database. Pandas inserts with `if_exists="append"` argument
so that it keeps the structure defined in SQL Alchemy.

```
import seaborn
import pandas
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Table, Column, Text, Float
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
```

Define metadata and create the table

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
meta = MetaData()
meta.bind = engine
iris_table = Table('iris',
                   meta,
                   Column("sepal_length", Float),
                   Column("sepal_width", Float),
                   Column("petal_length", Float),
                   Column("petal_width", Float),
                   Column("species", Text))
iris_table.create()
```

Load data into the table

```
iris = seaborn.load_dataset("iris")
iris.to_sql(name="iris",
            con=engine,
            if_exists="append",
            index=False,
            chunksize=10 ** 6,
            )
```

### Select unique values

Re using the `iris_table` from above.

```
from sqlalchemy import distinct, select
stmt = select(distinct(iris_table.c.species))
df = pandas.read_sql_query(stmt, engine)
df
#       species
# 0      setosa
# 1  versicolor
# 2   virginica
```

Answer (score 1):

the marked solution showed me an error so I just specified the column and it worked  here is the code

```
for i in (session.query(table_name.c.column_name).distinct()):
    print(i)
```